# Formatting text in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I´m stuck on a problem...
I´m trying to format text in powershell.

Here´s what I´m trying to do:

I´ve got a plain-text file containing the employee id and mail address from an ldap export which I´ve already cleaned up and looks like this:

```
0001  
a@y.com  
0002  
b@y.com  
0003  
c@y.com  
....  
0400
z@y.com
```

And I want convert this to the following:

```
0001,a@y.com  
0002,b@y.com  
0003,c@y.com  
...  
0400,z@y.com
```

The only thing which I´ve found so far is that I could create an output which will look like this:

```
0001,a@y.com,0002,b@y.com,0003,c@y.com...0400,z@y.com
```

Can someone help me with this?!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
 gc .\listfile.txt -ReadCount 2  | % { $_ -join ',' } | out-file .\newlist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to store the contents of the file:

```
$c=gc Myfile.txt
```

Then you will want to use a loop to print out every i-th and i+1-th line to a file:

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $c.Count;$i+=2){
    "$($c[$i]),$($c[$i+1])" | Out-File -Append MyNewFile.txt
}
```

Comment: I´m getting errors Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\convert1.ps1:3 char:4
+ $t[ <<<< $i+1]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (147:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray  But Christian´s posts has already helped me ;)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change my letters! $t --> $c